# wrong soname of shared library loaded at runtime Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I'm using eclipse cdt to compile and run C++ application.

My_main_program needs specifically *libjpeg.so.62*.

My Ubuntu system previously have *libjpeg.so.9* at `/usr/local/lib/`. I happened to compiled and run using *libjpeg.so.9* before run-time compatibility errors was raised.

Then I deleted all *libjpeg.** and installed *libjpeg.la, libjpeg.so, libjpeg.so.62 and libjpeg.so.62.0.0* from source. Then I run ldconfig.

I can build the project. The problem is the dynamic linker keeps searching for *libjpeg.so.9* and throwing

`'error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'`

at run-time. 
This problem is killing me.
I have checked that the symlink of libjpeg.so is correct.
Please help!

Comment: what `ldd` says ? is this missing library reachable for `ldconfig` ?

Comment: I deleted it as I have to use libjpeg.so.62.

Comment: ldd of the executable said 'libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.so.62 (0xb74af000)'

Comment: libjpeg.so.62 is already at /usr/local/lib/

Comment: and this is not your problem, `libjpeg.so.**9**` your eclipse is looking for another version of libjpeg, your should probably review your flags that you used to compile this stuff.

Comment: I think eclipse cdt knows which version to upload at run-time. I suspect that the symlink so soname stuck. But I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_general_pns_libpath.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can build the project. The problem is the dynamic linker keeps searching for libjpeg.so.9 and throwing

```
'error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.9: ... No such file ...
```

You need to understand a couple of things:

1. A shared library may have `SONAME` dynamic tag (visible with `readelf -d foo.so | grep SONAME`).
2. If an executable is linked against such a library, the `SONAME` is recorded as a `NEEDED` dynamic tag (in the executable), *regardless* of what the library itself is called. That is, you can name the library `foo.so`, `foo.so.1234`, or anything else. IF the library has `SONAME` of `libbar.so.7`, then the executable will require `libbar.so.7`, no matter what [1].

On to your problem. Your executable fails to load `libjpeg.so.9`, therefor we conclude that it is being linked (at build time) with a shared library which has `SONAME: libjpeg.so.9`.

> I deleted all libjpeg.* and installed libjpeg.so.62

You must not have deleted the libjpeg.so that is used at executable *build* time (which is somewhere other than `/usr/local/lib`). *That* library still has `SONAME: libjpeg.so.9`, and is causing you grief.

You can find out which libraries are being used at link time by passing `-Wl,-t` flag on the link line.

[1] Not strictly true: if the executable doesn't need any symbols from `foo.so`, and if `--as-needed` linker option is in effect, then `NEEDED: libbar.so.7` will not be recorded after all.

**Update**:

> I have also check ldd executable and it returns libjpeg.so.62

This means that the executable that you run `ldd` on is correct, but the executable that actually *run* is not, and they *must be* different executables.

**Update 2:**

> You're right. ldd executable shows both libjpeg.so.62 and libjpeg.so.9 are included

Actually, no, I wasn't. But I will be right this time.

What's happening is that your executable correctly records `NEEDED: libjpeg.so.62` (you can verify this with the following command: `readelf -d /path/to/exe | grep 'NEEDED.*libjpeg'`).

But you *also* have some other shared library (one of the ones listed in `ldd` output), which has *not* been rebuilt, and still has a dependency on `libjpeg.so.9`.

You can find that library by running `readelf -d /path/to/libXXX.so | grep 'NEEDED.*libjpeg\.so\.9'` on all libraries listed in `ldd` output.

Once you find it, you'll have to rebuild it so it also depends on `libjpeg.so.62`.

Comment: I've checked libjpg.so and it gives                            readelf -d /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.so | grep SONAME
 0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libjpeg.so.62]                                                      That's mean libjpeg.so is pointed to the correct .so.major

Comment: I have also check ldd executable and it returns        libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.so.62 (0xb76ff000)                                                         So, it seems that the executable also has recorded the correct soname. I have no clue which gives me the problem.

Comment: Thaks. You're right. ldd executable shows both libjpeg.so.62 and libjpeg.so.9 are included although I didn't include libjpeg.so.9.                                                         How can I remove libjpeg.so.9 from the executable?